# Custom label value copy in to string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two custom labels and one button in a cell .I want to move label value to another view on the click event of button ,not row select event,button also custom.

When i click button which showing in first cell then it should fetch first row label value .Or when other than fetch those row value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UILabel *inTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 12.0, 50.0, 20.0)];
     [inTime setTag:1];
     [inTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]; // transparent label background
     [inTime setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0]];
     // custom views should be added as subviews of the cell's contentView:
     [cell.contentView addSubview:inTime];

     UILabel *outTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0, 12.0, 50.0, 20.0)];
     [outTime setTag:2];
     [outTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]; // transparent label background
     [outTime setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0]];
     // custom views should be added as subviews of the cell's contentView:
     [cell.contentView addSubview:outTime];[(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] setText:[SlotsAvailable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     [(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2] setText:[slot_time_out objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: slotAvialable and slot_time_out is an mutable array

Comment: Where does "cell" come from? If you dequeue it, adding views to the cell will mix up everything!

Comment: If you defined cell as a property of your viewcontroller, then everything is mixed up anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get Index Path of selected button. And Set Tag Of Button. Using this tag value you can access value of selected button Row. Now, Button tag work as a index path of label. Please review below.

```
1) In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, assign button tag as index:

cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;

2) Add target and action for your button as below:

[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

3) Code actions based on index as below in ViewControler:

-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
     if (sender.tag == 0) 
     {
         // Your code here
        NSString *lbl1Str = [SlotsAvailable objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

        NSString *lbl2Str = [slot_time_out objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
     }
}
```

Comment: I have custom button and my selecter is this and here is how i add                                                                                                                         -(void) push {
    FinalDetailViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FinalDetailViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pushWithSlot animated:YES];
    
    pushWithSlot.getCenter1=getCenter;
    pushWithSlot.getCity1=getCity;
    
    }
    
    
}

Comment: @harshchauhan, Make your selector look like(push:) and your function/method will be: -(void)push:(UIButton*)sender{//Your code will be here-Do Stuff}

Comment: @harshchauhan, Ok. Can you solve your problem? If My Answer is helpful then accept it. so it will be used for another persons. Thanks! If you need any help then contact any time. Happy Coding!

Comment: sir-Could you send me your mail id.

Comment: @harshchauhan, Please find here: dadhaniya.renish@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can easly ..

```
- (void) yourButtonSelector:(uibutton*)button{

 NSString *lbl1Str = [SlotsAvailable objectAtIndex:button.tag];

 NSString *lbl2Str = [slot_time_out objectAtIndex:button.tag];

// do your stuff ..
}
```

hope it help you ..

Comment: @Garry-I don't want on did  select roe ,I want on button event which is available on my every row.

Comment: then set the tag of button  as indexpath.row & fetch  in  buttons selector methods  same  ..as